# Oracle query to get end of week from the given data set

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table in Oracle , where `EOW` columns indicate the end of week.
I want to write a query to get the nearest end of week date.

Table   Cal

```
DAY         DAY OFTHE WEEK      EOW

20181026    FRI                 Y  
20181027    SAT                 N  
20181028    SUN                 N  
20181029    MON                 N  
20181030    TUE                 N   -->
20181031    WED                 N  
20181101    THU                 N  
20181102    FRI                 Y  -->  
20181103    SAT                 N
```

So when I

```
select DAY , "logic" from cal where day = 20181030;
```

What should be "logic" so that I get the nearest end of week date , in this case
20181026.

Please help!!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the `next_date()` function? (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2037.htm#OLADM613)

Answer (score 0):

What I am guessing is,

```
 If the date is 30-OCT-2018 (20181030), then you want last friday date as 26-OCT - 2018 (20181026).
```

Another Scenario :

```
If the date is 27-OCT-2018 (20181027), in that case also you want last friday date which is 26-OCT - 2018 (20181026).
```

If my this is guess is true then below query may work :

```
   WITH TEMP1 AS
            (
             SELECT TO_CHAR(
                            TO_DATE('20181030','YYYYMMDD') ,'DD-MON-YY') AS DATE_TEST 
               FROM DUAL
             ) 
   SELECT next_day (TO_DATE(DATE_TEST,'DD-MON-YY')-7,'FRIDAY') Last_Friday
     FROM   TEMP1;
```

It will display output as :

```
   LAST_FRIDAY
   26-OCT-18
```

Which you can convert later in your required format.

Test Case 2

```
   WITH TEMP1 AS
        (
         SELECT TO_CHAR(
                        TO_DATE('20181103','YYYYMMDD') ,'DD-MON-YY') AS DATE_TEST 
           FROM DUAL
         ) 
   SELECT next_day (TO_DATE(DATE_TEST,'DD-MON-YY')-7,'FRIDAY') Last_Friday
 FROM   TEMP1;
```

Output :

```
 LAST_FRIDAY
 02-NOV-18
```

Now breaking of above query :

WITH clause is used in CTE.

```
  WITH TEMP1 AS
    (
     SELECT TO_CHAR(
                    TO_DATE('20181103','YYYYMMDD') ,'DD-MON-YY') AS DATE_TEST 
       FROM DUAL
     )
```

Here, TO_DATE('20181103','YYYYMMDD') ,'DD-MON-YY' - will convert 20181103 as 03-NOV-2018.

So the result from the WITH clause (Which is 03-NOV-2018) will be used in another query :

```
SELECT next_day (TO_DATE(DATE_TEST,'DD-MON-YY')-7,'FRIDAY') Last_Friday
  FROM   TEMP1;
```

Here DATE_TEST is output from with clause. First

```
 TO_DATE(DATE_TEST,'DD-MON-YY')-7
```

It is taking previous 7 days from the mentioned date (which is currently DATE_TEST : 03-NOV -2018) So It will take all the last 7 days from 03-NOV-2018.

Assuming :

```
DATE        DAY       Order
28-10-2018  SUN         1
29-10-2018  MON         2
30-10-2018  TUE         3
31-10-2018  WED         4
01-11-2018  THURS       5
02-11-2018  FRI         6
03-11-2018  SAT         7
```

We got all 7 days mentioned above.

```
next_day (TO_DATE(DATE_TEST,'DD-MON-YY')-7,'FRIDAY')
```

Now from next_day, we can get another day and here, we are asking for FRIDAY by mentioning it in the argument. So FRIDAY is 02-11-2018.

So the output will be 02-11-2018.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a *fixed* table for that? A CTE can easily create any calendar you want, so - I took that freedom to produce something like this.

I wrote it step-by-step so that you could follow its execution. Start from the first CTE (`dates`), then go to `day_diff`, and so forth). It seems that you are selecting the first FRI that precedes current date. Because, for 20181030, the nearest end-of-week isn't 20181026 (4 days to that Friday) but 20181102 (3 days to that Friday).

At the end, the result is

```
SQL> with dates as
  2    (select
  3      -- add "level" (sequence of numbers from 1 to 60) to 1st of previous month
  4      trunc(add_months(sysdate, - 1), 'mm') + level - 1 datum,
  5      -- convert that date into a day name (MON, FRI, ...)
  6      to_char(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'mm') + level - 1, 'DY',
  7              'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') dan,
  8      -- if day name is FRI, set EOW = Y. Else, it is N
  9      case when to_char(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'mm') + level - 1, 'DY',
 10                        'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'FRI' then 'Y'
 11           else 'N'
 12      end eow
 13     from dual
 14     connect by level <= 60  -- my CTE will have 60 dates; yours can have any number
 15    ),
 16  day_diff as
 17    (select datum, dan, eow,
 18       datum - to_date('&par_datum', 'dd.mm.yyyy') diff
 19    from dates
 20    ),
 21  diff_only_eow as
 22    (select datum, dan, eow, diff,
 23       row_number() over (order by diff desc) rn
 24     from day_diff
 25     where eow = 'Y'
 26       and diff <= 0
 27    )
 28  select datum, dan, eow, diff, rn
 29  from diff_only_eow
 30  where rn = 1;
Enter value for par_datum: 30.10.2018

DATUM    DAN          E       DIFF         RN
-------- ------------ - ---------- ----------
20181026 FRI          Y         -4          1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your query

```
select day, to_char(to_date(day,'YYYYMMDD'),'DY') f1,
    case to_char(to_date(day,'YYYYMMDD'),'DY')
        when 'FRI' then 0
        when 'SAT' then -1
        when 'SUN' then -2
        when 'MON' then -3
        when 'TUE' then 3
        when 'WED' then 2
        when 'THU' then 1
    end as f2,
    to_char(to_date(day,'YYYYMMDD')+ case to_char(to_date(day,'YYYYMMDD'),'DY')
        when 'FRI' then 0
        when 'SAT' then -1
        when 'SUN' then -2
        when 'MON' then -3
        when 'TUE' then 3
        when 'WED' then 2
        when 'THU' then 1
    end,'YYYYMMDD') as f3
from test_cal;


DAY      F1                F2 F3
-------- --------- ---------- --------
20181026 FRI                0 20181026
20181027 SAT               -1 20181026
20181028 SUN               -2 20181026
20181029 MON               -3 20181026
20181030 TUE                3 20181102
20181031 WED                2 20181102
20181101 THU                1 20181102
20181102 FRI                0 20181102
20181103 SAT               -1 20181102

9 rows selected.
```